# Which is the better way to obtain the final size of an UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, drawing

I'm wondering which is the better way to calculate and obtain the final size of an `UIView` that will be drawn dynamically. For example, I have a superview in wich a bunch of views will be drawn. I need the dimensions of those views to layout them properly, but its final size is dynamic taking into account the data they will be showing.

This way, I have to publish a class method to calculate and return the size of the view depending on the data to show, to create the view with the proper frame. After that, in the superview I layout the views correctly, and in the the `drawRect` of the subview almost duplicate that class method code, because I need those calculations to draw properly.

Example:

```
+ (CGSize)sizeForTopText:(NSString *)topText 
                leftText:(NSString *)leftText 
             showingIcon:(BOOL)showIcon {

    // Here I compute all this data taking into account font sizes, 
    // icon image size, etc, code that will be almost cloned in drawRect:
}

// In the superview

CGSize myViewSize = [MyView sizeForTopText:@"topText" leftText:@"leftText" showingIcon:NO];
MyView *theView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, myViewSize.width, myViewSize.height)];
```

I see that some Cocoa methods returns the final size after a draw, for example NSString's `drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:`, which returns the final size of the text after drawing it with that parameters.

How can I achieve something like that? I don't like the current solution, I think it's wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a layout issue that could be solved using the proper autolayout or strut/spring settings. Have you looked into using that instead of trying to calculate all of these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally shouldn't be calculating the size in `drawRect:`. You should have all the data you need a the point that the data is updated. And calculating it in a class method seems a little odd (though maybe it's fine if you need to call it from various places, but that still is uncommon).

The normal way to do this is to override `sizeThatFits:` for each subview. In there, calculate the optimal size based on the view's current configuration. Using `sizeToFit` will then tell the view to take on its optimal size. Your superview can use override `sizeThatFits:` to combine the results of its subviews, and you can use `sizeThatFits:` in `layoutSubviews` to calculate overall layout.